# Creating password protected ZIP file using TrueZip

Tags: java, truezip

Does anyone know any good example to creating password protected ZIP file using TrueZip?

I followed the the example given [TrueZip Example](http://truezip.java.net/truezip-driver/truezip-driver-zip/key-management.html) but while extracting password protected zip file is not accepting the correct password which I set through java code.

Comment: What tool you tried to extract password-protected file? Support for AES-encrypted ZIP files is not available in every application.

Comment: First I made the zip file through java code and as I need to make the password protected zip file I am using TrueZip as its has the eclipse license.

Comment: But what tool you tried to decompress that zip?

Comment: Please post your Java code. It will be hard to help by guesswork.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky : I am using windows explorer to extract the zip, it asks for password, but on entering the correct password it fails to extract the zip file

Comment: Windows explorer doesn't support AES-encrypted ZIP files.

Comment: Which tool I should be using ?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky : I tried to decry-pt through java code but I am getting this exception: "encrypted compression method 8 is not supported"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for this

```
try {
        final TConfig config = TConfig.get();

        // Request encryption in archive files.
        config.setOutputPreferences(config.getOutputPreferences()
                .or(BitField.of(FsOutputOption.ENCRYPT)));

        // Configure archive detector with custom key management for ZIP files.
        config.setArchiveDetector(newArchiveDetector1("zip", "password"));

        // Setup file paths.
        TFile src = new TFile("file1");
        TFile dst = new TFile("file2");
        if (dst.isArchive() || dst.isDirectory())
            dst = new TFile(dst, src.getName());

        // Recursive copy.
        src.cp_rp(dst);
    } finally {
        // Commit changes.
        TVFS.umount();
    }
```